# Alternating Summation of Catalan numbers $\pmod p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $C_n(x)={(2n)!\over (n+1)!(n!)}$ denote the $n$-th Catalan number: $C_0=1, C_1=1, C_2=2, C_3=5, C_4=14, C_5=42, ...$

If $p$ is an odd prime, prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k=(p-1)/2} (-1)^{n+1}{C_n}x^{k-n} \equiv -\left(\dfrac{x}{p}\right) \pmod p$$ if  $$\left(\dfrac{x^2+4x}{p}\right)\equiv1$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k=(p-1)/2} (-1)^{n+1}{C_n}x^{k-n} \equiv \left(\dfrac{x}{p}\right)(3+x) \pmod p$$ if

$$\left(\dfrac{x^2+4x}{p}\right)\equiv-1$$

Here is my idea for a proof:

Let $L(x)_n$ denote the $n$-th [Lucas Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials):

$$L(x)_{p-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{k=(p-1)/2} (-1)^{n}{C_n}x^{2(k-n)} \pmod p$$

also

$$L(x)_{p-1} = {u}^{p-1} + {u_2}^{p-1}$$

where $u, u_2 = ({(x ± \sqrt{x^2+4})\over2})$ are solutions to $u^2-ux-1 = 0$ It also appears that $u$ can be expanded into a Taylor Series and those terms should be easily reducible $\pmod p$.

I think this relates somehow to the polynomial in question, I am stuck on obtaining a closed form and series expansion for the closed form.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The [OEIS Sequence](http://oeis.org/A033297) for the alternating sum of Catalan numbers. It appears the claim is true for $x=1$.